# how do I write to avlibs AVOptions from C

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

I want to do the equivalent of the following command line from a C program.

```
ffmpeg ..... -movflags frag_keyframe
```

I have narrowed it down to setting some fields in priv_class in AVOutputFormat somehow. But I don't understand how AVOptions work, I could not find a good example that explains how AVOptions are set and used. I did come across av_opt_set but if I set the name field to "movflags" what is the val and do I set a separate option for frag_keyframe or is it embedded in the flags set for "movflags"? 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```cpp
AVFormatContext * _format_context = ...

AVDictionary * params = NULL;
av_dict_set(&params, "movflags", "frag_keyframe", 0);
avformat_write_header(_format_context, &params);
```